# Shared Libraries not linking together after installation with CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, linker

I have run into a rather strange problem with Google Tests.

In my project, I am using `externalProject_add` in order to download google tests and add them into my project. In my function, I believe I am asking for the project to be built, and then installed into a specific directory:

```
ExternalProject_Add(gTest_download
  URL ${GTEST_url}
  URL_HASH ${GTEST_hash}
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND cmake --build . --target install
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH=${Compiler_C}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH=${Compiler_CXX}
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<BINARY_DIR>/installation
)
```

I can then tell the program where all the source files are living with this:

```
ExternalProject_Get_Property(gTest_download BINARY_DIR)

set(gTest_LIBRARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR}/installation/lib CACHE INTERNAL "Google Test Binary Dir")
set(gTest_INCLUDE_DIR ${BINARY_DIR}/installation/include CACHE INTERNAL "Google Test Include Dir")
```

However, when I try to run a cmake test with protobufs I get the run time error:

`./Protobuf_test: error while loading shared libraries: libgmock.so.1.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Which is super odd, because I know I specifically told the program where to find the libraries in the same externalProject_add file:

```
set(gTest_LIBRARIES 
  ${gTest_LIBRARY_DIR}/${prefix}gmock${suffix}
  ${gTest_LIBRARY_DIR}/${prefix}gmock_main${suffix}
  ${gTest_LIBRARY_DIR}/${prefix}gtest${suffix}
  ${gTest_LIBRARY_DIR}/${prefix}gtest_main${suffix}
  CACHE INTERNAL "Google Test Libraries"
)
```

Where `${prefix}` is "lib" and `${suffix}` is ".lib". And I make sure to link them in my CMakeLists.txt file properly by doing `target_link_libraries(Protobuf_test ${gTest_LIBRARIES} ${protobuf_LIBRARIES})` ex:

```
CUSTOM_PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} hello.proto)

include_directories(
  ${protoBuf_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${gTest_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)

add_executable(Protobuf_test protobuf_test.cc ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDS})

add_dependencies(Protobuf_test 
  gTest_download 
  protoBuf_download
)

target_link_libraries(Protobuf_test 
  ${gTest_LIBRARIES} 
  ${protoBuf_LIBRARIES}
)

add_test(NAME testing_protobuf COMMAND Protobuf_test)
```

So I went into the installation folder which is located in `d/linuxBuild/lib/src/gTest_download-build/installation/lib` and confirmed it exists there. I then ran `ldd libgmock.so` and got the following output:

```
libgtest.so.1.11.0 => not found
```

Which I thought was odd as well. gtest is in the same directory! How is that possible? So I ran ldd on gmock_main:

```
libgmock.so.1.11.0 => not found
libgtest.so.1.11.0 => not found
```

So now I have two libraries that are in the same directory however they cannot be found. Confused, I decide to go to where the libraries should have originally installed to and copied over from. So two folders up: `d/linuxBuild/lib/src/gTest_download-build`. I then go into that folders lib folder and verify the libraries are there. I then run the same ldd command on gmock:

```
libgtest.so.1.11.0 => /mnt/d/linuxBuild/lib/src/gTest_download-build/lib/libgtest.so.1.11.0 (0x00007fb651729000)
```

I'm confused by this and again, run it on gmock_main:

```
libgmock.so.1.11.0 => /mnt/d/linuxBuild/lib/src/gTest_download-build/lib/libgmock.so.1.11.0 (0x00007f58b0db3000)
libgtest.so.1.11.0 => /mnt/d/linuxBuild/lib/src/gTest_download-build/lib/libgtest.so.1.11.0 (0x00007f58b0c9c000)
```

I am sorry for the lengthy question, but I need to know what happened here? Why is it when I install the libraries the links break from each other and they don't know their locations compared to the ones in the original installation path? Did their symbolic links break? Did I do something incorrectly in the CMake build? I'm scratching my head on this problem since I have never encountered this before. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question as asked, but `FetchContent()` is a lot more straightforward to use as you can just do `target_link_libraries(target gmock_main)` and have cmake take care of everything else.

Comment: @Frank is there a solid example that you know of that I can look at? I would personally love to move on from externalproject_add if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `externalProject_add` and use `FetchContent` / `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`, especially when dealing with CMake-ready projects:

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html for details

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        release-1.11.0
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# ...

target_link_libraries(Protobuf_test  
PRIVATE
  gmock_main
  ${protoBuf_LIBRARIES}
)
```

This way, you are linking against the `gmock_main` *target*, which will set up your libraries, includes, and any indirect dependencies correctly like any cmake project added via `add_subdirectory()` or `find_package()`.

Comment: does `FetchContent` work for all external projects? Like I can use this same sort of format with any of the google environments? Or something else like ZLib?

Comment: If the project has a `CMakeLists.txt` at the root of the repository, it's essentially equivalent to a `add_subdirectory()`, but there's a few other options as well. The link I added to the answer should have you covered. The examples section already covers Protobufs :).

Comment: If you're releasing a library, you need to be careful to allow a user to override your FetchContent dependency with `find_package`. Usually, you should try that first and then fall back to FC if it fails.